Using "some" in place of "sometimes"?
On TV, the presenter is asking a former couple a lot of quick questions to understand the current situation. Here is a small part of it:

Presenter to both guests: Are you two living together again?


Woman: No.


Presenter to the man: Are you staying over there some?


Man: Some, yeah.


Woman: Yes sometimes.* Dr. Phil (see:18:54-19:02)

As you can see, using "some" in place of "sometimes" happened two times during the conversation. Interestingly, it is not just the guest, the presenter uses it, too.
I had never heard some used in place of sometimes. Is it common?

American informal.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/some meaning 2

It's just you choosing to "paraphrase" some as sometimes in that context. I'd interpret it as more to some extent or on some occasions.

@FumbleFingers, Could the woman in the show saying "Yes, sometimes" be also choosing to paraphrase "some" as "sometimes."?

@AndyBonner Specifically it's pronoun meaning 2.

I think this use of "some" as a pronoun is particularly common in American southern dialects. It's not specifically "sometimes", it just means an indefinite number of whatever you're talking about.
